# Keep form elements selected after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I have a form with 5 elements (three dropdowns, date, text). When I click submit all the form elements get reset (dropdown gets assigned to first value, date and text field becomes blank).

I understand why this is happening - because my page is re-generated all the elements of the static form get initialized to their default value. Now, in order to preserve the selected values of form elements, I need to assign them to the form elements. I foresee doing that in following three ways:

---

***Option 1***

From the view, I return the selected values back to the template. Now during template generation I generate template options using django templates' for/if conditions (the ones that start with curly braces)

---

***Option 2*** -- Preferred

From the view, I return the selected values back to the template  and somehow pass those values to javascript. After that it will be a matter of getting hold of the static form elements using getElementById and assigning the values. However, I am not sure, how can I pass the returned value to javascript. Or should I write the script in the template itself?

---

***Option 3***

Use cache -- least interested

---

What do you suggest, I should do? Is there any other 4th option that is better and nicer? Submitting forms and preserving the form values seem like an essential part of web development. So, I am hoping there might be a better way.

EDIT: I am not using django's ModelForm. Rather I am using a simple html form and calling a view on submit (post)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand you correctly, but it almost sounds like you are missing something in your implementation. Make sure that when you initialize your form in your view, you send the posted data along to the form.

```
def your_form_view(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
```

Depending on how you are storing your input you'll just have to find a good way to supply your form with that date. If you are working with ModelForms you should instantiate your form like this instead:

```
model = YourModel.objects.get(id=123)
form = YourModelForm(request.POST, instance=model)
```

If you are not using ModelForms you can supply default values using the `initial` parameter instead.

Comment: ohh actually I am not using ModelForm. I just wrote a simple html form and passing it to a view using post.

Comment: That should not make a difference as long as you are supplying the form with `request.POST` as per my first example. If you do that the submitted values will persist after each (in)successful post request. If you wish for the to persist for subsequent GET requests as well you'll have to store them somewhere and supply them using the `initial` parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

1.Node.js server script:

```
const wordx = req.body.input1;
```

2.2.on your new html/ejs page(attention: this should a new html/ejs page):

```
<input class="inputAreas" name="input1" id="mainInput" value=<%= wordx %> autofocus required>
```

3.then again on the same page, open a script area, and:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      document.getElementById("mainInput").select();
    });
  </script>
```

I know you are using Django but this solution might help also.